# How to return the result of a function in the same page using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

This is simple but I don't seem able to make it happen in Codeigniter.

Using simple php it should be:

```
<form id="volume" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
<label>length(cm):</label>
<input type="text" name="length">
<label>width(cm):</label>
<input type="text" name="width">
<label>height(cm):</label>
<input type="text" name="height">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


<?php

$length = $_POST["length"];
$width = $_POST["width"];
$height = $_POST["height"];
$variable = 5000;

$sum_total = ($length * $width * $height) / $variable;

printf ("%01.2f" , $sum_total);

?> kg
```

I put the form in my view, the php in my controller but I want it to return the result in the same page instead of redirecting me.

Thank you all in advance for your responses.

Comment: To where is it redirecting you?

Comment: Have you tried writing any jQuery code at all?

Comment: The older `$PHP_SELF` doesn't work when `register_globals = Off`. Use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put jQuery similar to this on the page with your submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#volume').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var post_array = {
        length: $('input[name=length]').val();
        width: $('input[name=width]').val();
        // etc
    };

    $.post('path/to/controller/method', post_array, function(data){
        alert(data); // do stuff;
    }

    return false; //to stop the form from submitting
  });
});
```

Put the PHP that calculates the result in 'path/to/controller/method' and have it `return $result;`.

When a user clicks the submit button it will submit an ajax request to your new view and return the result to jQuery where you can then change the page or w/e you want to do.

Comment: It seems to be right but it still redirects me to my controller/method url

Comment: Interesting. I'd figure out why. `return false;` should stop that form from submitting. Check your console for syntax errors and stuff.

Comment: I have corrected all syntax errors, but still redirects me there. I'll look into it and will let you know. You have been really helpful! Will accept the answer when I figure it out.

Comment: Double check your code. Here is a jsFiddle showing how `return false;` works: http://jsfiddle.net/FSrT9/

Comment: Wrap your code in a `$(document).ready();` call. Maybe thats the reason it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`. Keep in mind that for a post (unless using ajax calls), a refresh of the page is required.